# PHP SDK, login - go to url and post to wall

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I made an app that will allow users to upload one photo/video from localhost (exhibition) to their own wall.

now what I am trying to do is to get the FB login page and after a successful login to redirect to a "please wait..." page that will run the upload code in background. otherwise the user has to wait after logging in without knowing whats happening.

i tried the

```
"next" => "myurl",
```

but it doesnt work.

i am using php sdk.

do you have any ideas / references?

**Edit:**

My code for login dialog:

```
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'photo_upload, publish_stream, share_item', 'next' => 'http://www.google.com') );

header ("Location: $login_url");
```

I want to redirect this to a preloader html page and then upload using the normal upload code found in my upload.php

Comment: can you post the code with longer length that includes more details you did?

Comment: yes, sorry. does it make any sens? i updated the initial post.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the redirect_uri like this:

```
$facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope'        => 'photo_upload, publish_stream, share_item',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://your.preloadpage'
));
```

Comment: thank you guys! I will give it a try and get back to you! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here is an example

```
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
'scope' => 'photo_upload, publish_stream, share_item',
'fbconnect' => 1,
'canvas' => 0,
'next' => 'http://localhost/demo/facebook/index.php',
'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/demo/facebook/index.php',
));
```

param "next" indicates the url to be redirected after clicking a "finish"

param "redirect_uri" indicates the url to be redirected after the progressing to the next page.

and the hosts of `redirect_uri` and `next` are ought to be yours ,set and added in the facebook app settings.

Comment: Thank you Abby! what about canvas and fbconnect? 
I will give it a try and get back here! Thanks!

Comment: canvas: set this to ’1′ for canvas application.  Otherwise, ignore it.
fbconnect: set this to ’0′ for canvas application.  Otherwise, ignore it. (The default is 1 which is for fbconnect app.)